# new NewCookie NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cookies, java-ee-7, nosuchmethoderror

I'm trying to create a `new cookie` to use with my Java app, but I get the following error:

`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;IZZ)V`

This is how I'm creating the `cookie`

```
int cookieAge = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60;

NewCookie cookie = new NewCookie("mysession",
        "somevalue",
        "/",
        "*",
        "",
        cookieAge,
        false,
        true
);
```

This is what I'm using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

EDIT:

Nothing wrong when I create it like this:

```
NewCookie cookie = new NewCookie("mysession", "Somevalue");
```

Answer (score 0):

You compile your code with the 7.0 dependency which works fine. However, your scope is `provided` which means that you let a container provide the dependency which is very likely the `javaee-api` in a version older/different than 7.0 that doesn't have that particular signature of the `NewCookie` constructor and fails at runtime.

Check with the version of your application server/container which dependencies/libs it provides in which version. Either you go and upgrade your container or you downgrade your compile-time dependency to a lower version.